# singular cohomology and Poincaré duality

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology, poincare-duality

Suppose $M$ is a n-dimensional, finite type, oriented, smooth manifold. A $k$-dimensional cycle in $M$ is a pair ($S$,$\phi$), where $S$ is a compact, oriented $k$-dimensional manifold without boundary, and $\phi$: $S$ → $M$ is a smooth map. A $k$-cycle ($S$, $\phi$) defines a linear map $H^k(M)\rightarrow R$ given by $w \mapsto \int_S \phi^* w$ where $w \in H^k(M)$ and $\phi^*$ is the pullback. In other words, that each cycle defines an element in $(H^k(M))^*$. Via the Poincaré duality we identify the vector space $(H^k(M))^∗$ with $H^{n−k}_{cpt}(M)$ where $H^{n-k}_{cpt}(M)$ denotes the compactly supported cohomology group.  Thus there exists $\delta_S \in H^{n−k}_{cpt}(M)$, such that
\begin{align}
\int_M w \wedge \delta_S=\int_S \phi^*w.
\end{align}
The compactly supported cohomology class $\delta_S$ is called the Poincare dual of the pair $(S, \phi)$.

My question is that: since in the above formula uses the wedge product, it is more or less related to De Rham cohomology(not?). **Can the above formula be rephrased into the language of singular cohomology?** More explicitly, consider a triangulation $\Gamma$ of $M$, and a $k$-cycle ($S,\phi)$  can be represented by a singular $k$-cycle, denoted as $C_S$ and the cohomology class $w$ can also defined in the singular cohomology sense, so we still use $w$ to denote it. Then I try to rephrase the above formula as
\begin{align}
C_S \cap w= \Gamma \cap (w\cup w_S) 
\end{align}
or equivalently 
\begin{align}
\int_{C_S} w= \int_{\Gamma} w\cup w_S
\end{align}
where $w_S \in H^{n-k}(\Gamma)$ is the  Poincaré dual of $C_S$ in $\Gamma$, so that $w \cup w_S \in H^n(\Gamma)$, parallel to $\delta_S$ defined above. $\cap$ is the cap product and $\cup$ means the cup product. Do this rephrase make sense? Is this $w_S$ right to be Poincaré dual of $C_S$?